# browser doesn't response well to https proxy

Tags: python, sockets, https, proxy

I'v built my own https proxy and when ever I send some data to a browser the browser responses with nothing and also after a lot of time.
basically all the proxy should do is just forward the message to browser, get the response and forward back to the client

the code of the proxy:

```
import socket
import select



serverSock = socket.socket()
serverSock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8080))
serverSock.listen(3)
waiting_clients = {} # client : browser
users_dict = {}
open_clients = {}
browsers_clients = {} # browser : client

threading.Thread(target=browserCom).start()
while True:
    try:
        rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select(list(users_dict.keys()) + [serverSock], [], [], 0.3)
    except:
        pass
    else:
        for current_socket in rlist:
            if current_socket is serverSock:
                # new client
                client, address = serverSock.accept()
                print(f'{address} - connected to proxy')
                # add to dictionary
                users_dict[client] = address
                open_clients[address] = client
            else:
                # receive info
                receiving = True
                msg = bytearray()
                while receiving:
                    try:
                        data = current_socket.recv(1024)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e, 3)
                        if current_socket in users_dict.keys():
                            disconnect(users_dict[current_socket])

                        else:
                            current_socket.close()
                        break
                    else:
                        msg.extend(data)
                        # got the full msg
                        if len(data) < 1024:
                            receiving = False
                if len(msg) == 0:
                    if current_socket in users_dict.keys():
                        disconnect(users_dict[current_socket])
                else:

                    print("GOT FROM CLIENT", msg)
                    if current_socket in waiting_clients.keys():
                        # sending  the data from client to browser
                        waiting_clients[current_socket].send(msg)
                    

                    else:
                        msg = msg.decode()
                        msgSplit = msg.split()
                        address = msgSplit[1]

                        if address.split(':')[1].isnumeric():
                            if msg.startswith('CONNECT'):
                                browserLink, browserPort = address.split(':')
                                browserPort = int(browserPort)
                                browserIP = socket.gethostbyname(browserLink)
                                address = (browserIP, browserPort)
                                # connect to the site
                                browserSocket = socket.socket()
                                print(address)
                                browserSocket.connect((browserIP, browserPort))
                                waiting_clients[current_socket] = browserSocket
                                browsers_clients[browserSocket] = current_socket
                                msg_ret = "HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established\r\n\r\n"
                                sendMsg(users_dict[current_socket], msg_ret)
                                m
```

The proxy is able to make the connection after the CONNECT and notify to the client but after I send to the browser I got from the data with a function running in the background:

```
def browserCom():
    while True:
        try:
            rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select(list(browsers_clients.keys()), [], [], 0.3)
        except:
            pass
        else:
            for current_browser in rlist:
                # receive data from the browser
                receiving = True
                resp_msg = bytearray()
                while receiving:
                    try:
                        data = current_browser.recv(1024)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
                        del waiting_clients[browsers_clients[current_browser]]
                        current_browser.close()
                        browsers_clients[current_browser].close()
                        del browsers_clients[current_browser]

                    else:
                        resp_msg.extend(data)
                        # got the full msg
                        if len(data) < 1024:
                            receiving = False

                print("RESPONSE FROM BROWSER", resp_msg)
                # sending the msg to the client
                sendMsg(users_dict[browsers_clients[current_browser]], resp_msg)
```

I need to wait a lot of time for the response and most of the responses come empty the responses are mostly bytearray(b'') and even when I get the response even though I sent the response back to the client:

```
# sending the msg to the client
sendMsg(users_dict[browsers_clients[current_browser]],resp_msg)
```

using this

```
def sendMsg(address, msg):
        """
    
        :param ip: ip to send to
        :param msg: msg to send
        :return: sends the msg to the ip
        """
        if address in open_clients.keys():
            sock = open_clients[address]
            if type(msg) == str:
                msg = msg.encode()
            try:
                sock.send(msg)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e, 4)
                disconnect(address)
```

I hope you are abled to understand my code, please if something is unclear ask me in the comments and I will try to help you understand as soon as possible

this is the best that I can do to keep the code minimal for this problem without removing crucial parts

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, which might be because is incomplete. You show only the parts which you deem relevant, but I don't think this is sufficient. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'v read about it and updated the code I hope it's better now

Comment: From a short look at the code two things stand out. First, you seem to assume that inside the CONNECT tunnel there will only be data from client to server followed by data from server to client. This assumption is wrong, data will be send in both directions multiple times inside a TLS connection. Second, you are using blocking sockets and assume that if you read all the 1024 bytes requested then more data will be available. This assumptions is wrong if there were exactly 1024 bytes to read - in which case your code will block.

Comment: I'm using "select" which opens a thread for every client and I receive from the sockets inside the rlist, the rlist is the list of all the sockets who send data, means I won't be stuck on a receive , however I do assume that there is always one message between the two but still it doesn't explain why the server doesn't send any data at all

Comment: *"I'm using "select" which opens a thread"* - select does not open any threads. All your code here is running within a single thread and any blocking recv or accept on one socket will mean that no progress will be made for any other sockets either.

Comment: *"but whenever I get the data to send to the browser the response is always bytearray(b'')"* - it is unclear to me which part of your code you refer to. Please be more specific.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that I am mistaken about the select, I'v updated the code so you will able to understand to which part of the code I'm reffering

Comment: While you in theory support multiple clients and multiple upstream connections at the same time you use only a single `browserSocket` to actually read from upstream. Shouldn't it be instead `waiting_clients[current_socket]` ? `browserSocket` might refer to the upstream of a different client.

Comment: Ho I didn't notice that haha , I will try to run it again and give you an answer if it worked

Comment: I tried to run it, it seems that I do get a response sometimes now but It still takes a lot of time to get the response and some of the responses are still empty do you know why?

Comment: This is then a different problem than described currently and with a different code than shown. Please update the question to reflect the changes. Also show all the necessary code to reproduce the problem, including imports and definition of sendMsg. And clearly describe how exactly the issue shows up and how the problem can be reproduced by others.

Comment: I'v updated the problem now

Comment: There is still the wrong expectation I've mentioned earlier: *" you seem to assume that inside the CONNECT tunnel there will only be data from client to server followed by data from server to client. This assumption is wrong, data will be send in both directions multiple times inside a TLS connection"*. You simply wait for the server to close the connection - that's what causes the problems you see. Instead you need to check for reads on both client and server side and then transfer the read data from each side to the other.

Comment: it seems to be working now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that I didn't understand that while tunneling both the browser and the client exchange messages, adding another select to all the browser helped me check all the data from all the browsers and now it works.

The code above is updated and works

basically what I added is :

```
def browserCom():
while True:
    try:
        rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select(list(browsers_clients.keys()), [], [], 0.3)
    except:
        pass
    else:
        for current_browser in rlist:
            # receive data from the browser
            receiving = True
            resp_msg = bytearray()
            while receiving:
                try:
                    data = current_browser.recv(1024)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    del waiting_clients[browsers_clients[current_browser]]
                    current_browser.close()
                    browsers_clients[current_browser].close()
                    del browsers_clients[current_browser]

                else:
                    resp_msg.extend(data)
                    # got the full msg
                    if len(data) < 1024:
                        receiving = False
            # disconnecting browser
            if resp_msg == bytearray(b''):
                del waiting_clients[browsers_clients[current_browser]]
                current_browser.close()
                browsers_clients[current_browser].close()
                del browsers_clients[current_browser]

            print("RESPONSE FROM BROWSER", resp_msg)
            # sending the msg to the client
            if current_browser in browsers_clients and browsers_clients[current_browser] in users_dict:
                sendMsg(users_dict[browsers_clients[current_browser]], resp_msg)
```